# gnuplot looping data files and an iterator for 3D plot

Tags: plot, iteration, gnuplot

I'm trying to plot a set of 2D data files onto a single 3D plot, like a fence plot. I'm having trouble creating two iterators to loop both the data files and the x-axis values at the same time though.

I tried something like this:

```
list = system('dir /b *.csv')
x = 0
do for [file in list] {
    splot file using (x):1:2 with l
    x=x+1
}
```

which doesn't seem to work. I get the initial plot, but none of the later entries. The actual file and variable is iterating, but I'm guessing the variable is calculated once and not updated inside the splot command.

The amount of data I want to work with makes defining the file list and the x axis value a non-trivial task. Otherwise I would just do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use function to change variable.

```
list = system('dir /b *.csv')
f(x)=(x=x+1, x-1)
x = 0
splot for [file in list] file using (f(x)):1:2 w l
```

Comment: That's perfect, it works exactly like I wanted. Thanks so much!